# Ruby String can't be coerced into Fixnum

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a program for computing GPAs from student records. After entering a student's last and first name I am getting these errors:

```
Please provide the last name of the desired student:  
Cirello  
Please provide the first name of the desired student:  
Brian  
proj3.rb:55:in `+': String can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)  
        from proj3.rb:55:in `block in <main>'  
        from proj3.rb:53:in `each'  
        from proj3.rb:53:in `<main>'
```

Please help me out on this issue. Here is my code:

```
stud_id = []
last_name = []
first_name = []
course_number = []
course_name = []
prof_name = []
credit_hours = []
grade = []

grade_values = {                          
    "A" => 4,                     
    "B" => 3,
    "C" => 2,
    "D" => 1,
    "F" => 0 }

fin = File.open("student-records.txt", "r")

while line = fin.gets
    fields = line.chomp.split(',')
    stud_id << fields[0]
    last_name << fields[1]
    first_name << fields[2]
    course_number << fields[3]
    course_name << fields[4]
    prof_name << fields[5]
    credit_hours << fields[6]
    grade << fields[7]
end

fin.close

puts "Please provide the last name of the desired student:"
    desired_last_name = gets.chomp
puts "Please provide the first name of the desired student:"
    desired_first_name = gets.chomp

desired_student_credit_hours = 0
desired_student_grades = 0
desired_student_indexes = [7]
if last_name.include?(desired_last_name) && first_name.include?(desired_first_name)
    last_name.each do |student_last_name, i|
        if student_last_name == desired_last_name
            desired_student_indexes << i
        end
    end
end
desired_student_indexes.each do |desired_student_index|
    desired_student_grades += grade_values[grade[desired_student_index]]
    desired_student_credit_hours += credit_hours[desired_student_index]
end
final_gpa = desired_student_grades / desired_student_credit_hours
puts "This student's final GPA is: #{final_gpa}"
```

Comment: Your data structure is a bit confusing. Consider storing each student in a hash or a Struct object.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the `to_i` method that converts a string to an integer. You need to append it to both `grade_values[grade[desired_student_index]]` and `credit_hours[desired_student_index]` like so:

```
desired_student_grades += grade_values[grade[desired_student_index]].to_i
desired_student_credit_hours += credit_hours[desired_student_index].to_i
```

Comment: thanx what about the cumputing part it still giving me an error when i enter the name?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. What error? Did my suggestion not fix the error reported in the original question?

Comment: @cooler please ask one question at a time. If you are now having different issues, it might be better to open a new question that exactly tackles your new problem.